# xna collision without max speed

Tags: c#, xna, 2d, collision

I'm making a platform game and I've looked at different ways to add collisions in a tile based game without rotation. But everything I look at assumes that in no case will one of the colliding objects be going fast enough to pass the other before collision is detected. I've tried using Box2D and Farseer but they were over complicated and ran quite slowly when making lots of tiles. I also tried my own method using 2D convex hulls but that ran too slowly as well. So is there a way to to detect collisions without a maximum speed or letting items pass each other that isn't over complicated and would work with lots of tiles? any help is much appreciated

Comment: Every algorithm you'll find/implement will have limitations on number of items and run slow when you add more and more objects - there is nothing you can do about that. There is not much to say here except - set goal, profile and see what is slow in your case. Adding approximate checks (like bounding rectangles that also include speed/time) and some sort bucketing objects based on position in space  before precise checks are possible approaches to optimize...

Answer (score 1):

Depend on objects and their movement and whole gameplay. if you are shooting bullet to some obstacle, you can calculate if bullet will intersect with obstacle before bullet hit it. you have positions, you can calculate distance between them. so you can check collision and distance.

other way, as **@cwohlman** suggested. you can have 2 collision boxes, one big "assumed" collision area and one excact that cover objects. so if object triggers assumed collision, you know that there i a chance that bullet will hit object and you do some detailed calculations if button will hit object or will pass above or under it. for determinating if object is in assumed collision area you can use circle collsion.

```
private bool DetectCircularCollision(Sprite a, Sprite b)
{
    float radius = Math.Sqrt(a.Width / 2 * a.Height / 2 + b.Width / 2 * b.Height / 2);
    float distance = Vector2.Distance(a.Position, b.Position);
    if (distance < radius) return true;
    return false;
}
```

so far i didn't encounter this problem, as all flying objects should be visible to players eye. if you move object 50px or 100px per frame player will not notice this or will be confused what is this.

You will probably need to combine few collision methods to achieve what you need. Advice, do not use pixel collsion as it's completly unnecessary and it's resuorce killer. Instead, cover objects with few bounding boxes or circles.

example where blue circle is assumed collision area, and red circles are exact collision area.

[image]
[image]

Comment: sounds good. does anyone know how i might go about making an algorithm for the "if they really collided" part?  Also all my tiles and characters have rectangular collision boxes. would it be more effective to have the larger collision box as a box or a circle?

Comment: box collision is faster then circle, i use circle as it better cover objects. also then you can calculate bounce angle, add some damage effects better than in rectangle. visually more acurate. i added another image when you use box and circle. same size, you can see that collision (blue) is more accurate.

Comment: to "will they collide" you can calculate using only one pixel (vector2) so if location of that pixel is inside other object there is a chanse that will colide. and if they really colide, calculate collision using slower object motion. instead of velocity.x=20 use velocity.y=1 in loop.

Answer (score 0):

You might try a dual algorithm approach, using a simple algorithm first to deturmine if the objects 'might' have collided and if if so, use a complex algorithm to see if they did collide.